# Boot Camp as a virtual drive?

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows

Issue: I have a car that requires Win.XP Pro 32-bit OS to access and update the software.

Is it possible to install Win.XP Pro 32-bit OS on a MacBook Pro running Mojave 10.14.2?

Comment: If it's for a one-off I'd look at something like VirtualBox, free & disposable

Comment: I heard that before, but I had an overload@ that moment in time, an it escaped me. I'll do that!!    thank you.

Comment: fyi. The standard version of windows will not run on an external drive. You would need windows enterprise to install on an external drive via bootcamp.  You can play around with VirtualBox to put the Windows files for VirtualBox on an external drive.  Windows will think that it is running on an internal drive.  I done this.

Comment: I've linked this to our canonical question on how to run windows on Mac. If there's a need to edit this once you've selected one specific method - please make an edit to the post to narrow down what specifically you need to get solved based on what path you choose.